# How to find a common element in two columns with Kusto (KQL)? Objective: find matching IPs to CIDRs

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

this is the dataset (image below):

[image: dataset]

**Objective:**

1. find in both the SrcIP_s and DestIP_s columns elements that match a dynamic list of CIDRs (i.e. probably using ipv4_is_in_range())

In my silly attempts I managed two find matching CIDRs in both columns using mv-apply, but the end result only shows results when they match **simultaneously both columns**, which is not the expected result.

```
let customer_cidrs = dynamic(['172.16.1.128/27']);
AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL
| mv-apply SrcCIDR = customer_cidrs to typeof(string) on (where ipv4_is_in_range(SrcIP_s, SrcCIDR))
| mv-apply DestCIDR = customer_cidrs to typeof(string) on (where ipv4_is_in_range(DestIP_s, DestCIDR))
| project FlowDirection_s, SrcIP_s, DestIP_s, InMiBytes=round((InboundBytes_d/1048576),2), OutMiBytes=round((OutboundBytes_d/1048576),2)
```

**Restriction:**

- the *MiBytes data must be preserved (later I intend to sum it all, thus obtaining a comprehensive figure of how many Bytes each matching CIDR exchanged)

**Expected result:**

show all lines that match **EITHER** SrcIP_s or the DestIP_s columns without changing any other column value (i.e. exclude rows that don't match a customer_cidrs element).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to see if using the [ipv4_lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-lookup-plugin) is going to work better for you rather than [ipv4_is_in_range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-is-in-range-function).  It sounds like it could be a good fit for your use case.

```
let customer_cidrs = datatable (CIDR:string, Customer1:string) [
'172.16.1.128/27', 'Contoso',
'10.10.1.0/24', 'Wingtip',
'192.168.1.0/24', 'Northwind'
];
let AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL_T = datatable (FlowDirection_s:string, SrcIP_s:string, DestIP_s:string, InMiBytes:real, OutMiBytes:real)[
'I', '172.16.1.69', '172.16.1.132', 0.06, 0.04,
'I', '172.16.1.101', '172.16.1.132', 0.0, 0.0,
'I', '192.168.0.10', '192.168.1.50', 10.2, 15.7,
'O', '172.16.1.132', '1.1.1.1', 0.04, 0.0,
'O', '192.168.1.100', '10.10.1.14', 0.1, 1.6
];
AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL_T
| evaluate ipv4_lookup(customer_cidrs, SrcIP_s, CIDR, return_unmatched=true)
| evaluate ipv4_lookup(customer_cidrs, DestIP_s, CIDR, return_unmatched=true)
| where isnotempty(coalesce(Customer1, Customer11))
```

Comment: Thanks @Gyp. That did it. There's a typo in your answer: return_unmacthed should be return_unmatched. If you fix it, I'll accept as an answer.

Comment: Typo fixed, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

> TO check either the SrcIP_s or DestIP_s columns elements that match a dynamic list of CIDRs

**KQL code:**

```
let customer_cidrs = dynamic(['172.16.1.128/27']);
AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL
| mv-apply SrcCIDR = customer_cidrs to typeof(string), DestCIDR = customer_cidrs to typeof(string) on (where ipv4_is_in_range(SrcIP_s, SrcCIDR) or ipv4_is_in_range(DestIP_s, DestCIDR) )//
| project FlowDirection_s, SrcIP_s, DestIP_s, InMiBytes=round((InboundBytes_d/1048576),2), OutMiBytes=round((OutboundBytes_d/1048576),2)
```

This query uses the mv-apply operator to apply the customer_cidrs list to both the SrcCIDR and DestCIDR variables. Then, it uses the where operator to filter the results to only include rows where either the SrcIP_s or DestIP_s columns match one of the CIDRs.

[Demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42SXW+CMBSG7/kVvaNNmFAi6jReOM0Sk31luzSmQehcN2xJWzQs+/FrESbiloyTkHJ4znmbc96MajD7LCR9oPog5MeMx1mpWaLI/G4K0lib2GQU3mbisGCSJpoJTtRYacn41gMvMlk+tb4XVOmzxJJvRMHTm1JTRdJxJmzysdAXWeSsHGAet/npesDFQc9Gv3WOzBkHgQdC8zpW1Bo1hGuoXRwZHkcNf6ZwHfbwYGSqTFObGPWqqIqCSuoXmRN00WBotcIocNYTJzPTTQqlxY5KkrBUKmCGWvJ4xxK4ai6IfTxw12ji/LUI5wvs9ldxnmelHfh8uXg2fTqNtQC6zKl4hcfRo+My/gkDwQE8vFFJAcv3fcIUYZzImG8prHfsNdoGlpdUs/mTLALI983dcynejXFAx0M/5jm5xtrlnlWumEo7awjP/ePjoD+KhgPkhaiyUYfuGKuNfwOMcdOb6gIAAA==)

Comment: Thanks, @aswin, but in your example if there's a match on any of the IP columns, both the CIDR columns get overwritten, which should not be the case. I.e.: 10.1.0.5 is not part of 10.0.0.0/16, but its corresponding SrcCIDR column still receives a row value of 10.0.0.0/16.

Comment: Could you share few more data to explain this?